# Loading HTML text into UITableViewCells creates a delay in rendering the UI, Any workaround to lazily load html text?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

When you convert HTML tags into Attributed text using, `init(data:options:documentAttributes:)` initialiser on NSAttributed String, It takes considerable amount of time to load on first call (As Data conversion is happening on main thread) which creates delay in rendering UI, I haven't found any approaches showing how to lazily render HTML text, So what's the best approach to load HTML text & avoid delay in rendering the UI ?

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

```
   DispatchQueue.global().async {
        //Load HTML Here
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           //Assign it to your textview or label or any UI updation task.
        }
    }
```